# how customize filtering Client Template kendo grid column asp.net mvc 5

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, kendo-grid, client-templates

I have a kendo grid that contain a column with client template containing three type of icone, I would like to be able to filter this column with the three icon but i didn't find a solution for my question ? please help me this is my code:

```
columns.Bound(p => p.x).ClientTemplate(
            " # if (x == -1) { #  <img src='***** />  # } #"
             + " # if (x == 0) { #  <img src='***# } #"
             + " # if (x == 1) { #  <img src='**** />   # } #"
            ).Filterable("???????").Title("").Width(20);
        columns.Bound(c => c.Code)
            .Groupable(false);
```

Any help please